# Proving that Levi-Civita connection is preserved by isometries

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, connections

I am trying to prove that given two Riemannian submanifolds $S,S'$ with Levi-Civita connections $\nabla , \nabla'$ and an isometry $f$, then 
$$
Df(\nabla_XY)=\nabla'_{X'}Y'
$$
where, $X',Y'=Df(X),Df(Y)$.
The argument is that if $\nabla''_XY=D f^{-1}(\nabla '_{X'}Y')$ torsion free and metric then it is the Levi-Civita connection on $S$. I was trying to prove this is metric and this is what I get: 
$$
g(\nabla''_XY,Z)+g(Y,\nabla''_XZ)=g(D f^{-1}(\nabla '_{X'}Y'),Z)+g(Y,D f^{-1}(\nabla '_{X'}Z'))
$$
$$
=g'(\nabla '_{X'}Y',Z)+g'(Y',\nabla '_{X'}Z')
$$
as $f$ is isometry, and as $\nabla'$ is Levi-Civita,
$$
=X'g'(Y',Z')=X'g(Y,Z)
$$
which should have been $Xg(Y,Z)$... Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? also is there a more efficient way to show what I want to prove instead of checking that $\nabla''$ is metric and torsion free (and also that it is a connection)?

This is not a duplicate I showed my working and I want to know why my working does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f:(S,g)\to (S',g')$ is an isometry, then define
$\nabla_{X'}Y':=df\ \nabla_XY$

Show that this is LC-connection :

(1) Compatibility condition : First show that $$ X'(Y',Z')=X(Y,Z)$$

Proof : If $\frac{d}{dt}p(t)=X,\ p(0)=p$ then
$$ df_p X(df_p Y, df_p Z) =\frac{d}{dt} (df Y, df Z)_{f(p(t))} =
\frac{d}{dt} (Y,Z)_{p(t)}
$$ since $f$ is an isometry And $\frac{d}{dt} (Y,Z)_{p(t)}= X(Y,Z)$

So $$ (\nabla_{X'}Y',Z')+(Y',\nabla_{X'}Z')=f^\ast g'( \nabla_XY,Z)
+ f^\ast g' (Y,\nabla_XZ) = X(Y,Z) =X'(Y',Z') $$

(2) Symmetry condition : $$ \nabla_{X'}Y' -\nabla_{Y'}X'=df
(\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX)=df[X,Y]=[X',Y']$$

Comment: okay sorry but can you have a look at what I wrote in the question and tell me why it is wrong?

Comment: oh but I wrote let me copy paste for you

Comment: X′,Y′=Df(X),Df(Y)

Comment: ∇′′XY=Df−1(∇′X′Y′)

Comment: $\nabla''$ is a second connection which I define to be what I wrote

Comment: and then I show that $\nabla''$ is metric and torsion free, hence by uniqness of levi civita it ust be $\nabla$

Comment: well I explained to you what he has written

Comment: he needs to replace $\nabla$ by $\nabla''$

Comment: @ Alex M : Yes $S$ has a connection. From this we define $\nabla'$ on $S'$ That is to say $(\nabla')_{X'}Y' :=df \nabla_XY$ Then in fact connection defined from that of $S$ satisfies LC-connection conditions. So uniqueness of LC-connection implies that connection defined is connection of $S'$

Comment: $f$ is an isometry. Please see the title.

Comment: @ sifsa : Please see the (1) in my answer for $X'(Y',Z') = X(Y,Z)$

Comment: @Alex M isometry is not local isometry, ie it is diffeomorphism too

Comment: Yes I understand alphago thank you

Comment: @AlexM. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry_%28Riemannian_geometry%29